# Read HDF5 based file as a numpy array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, hdf5

How can I load in a `.hws` file as a numpy array?
Based on the description in http://kingler.net/2007/05/22/90 which says it is a HDF5 based format, so I found https://confluence.slac.stanford.edu/display/PSDM/How+to+access+HDF5+data+from+Python might be useful. However, by following the instruction described in the page:

```
hdf5_file_name = '/reg/d/psdm/XPP/xppcom10/hdf5/xppcom10-r0546.h5'
dataset_name   = '/Configure:0000/Run:0000/CalibCycle:0000/Camera::FrameV1/XppSb4Pim.1:Tm6740.1/image'
event_number   = 5
file    = h5py.File(hdf5_file_name, 'r')  
dataset = file[dataset_name]
arr1ev  = dataset[event_number]
file.close()
```

I got error in the sixth line after I fixed the first three line as my case:

```
file_name = '~/Desktop/audioData_A.hws'
item = h5py.File(file_name, 'r')
print item.name 
ds = item['/']
print len(ds)
arr1ev = ds[1]
```

which returns:

```
<HDF5 group "/" (1 members)>
1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-b33014aeccc8> in <module>()
      4 ds = item['/']
      5 print len(ds)
----> 6 arr1ev = ds[1]

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_objects.so in     h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/Users/travis/build/MacPython/h5py-wheels/h5py/h5py/_objects.c:2405)()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_objects.so in   h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/Users/travis/build/MacPython/h5py-wheels/h5py/h5py/_objects.c:2362)()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/group.pyc in __getitem__(self,  name)
    158                 raise ValueError("Invalid HDF5 object reference")
    159         else:
--> 160             oid = h5o.open(self.id, self._e(name), lapl=self._lapl)  
    161 
    162         otype = h5i.get_type(oid) 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/base.pyc in _e(self, name, lcpl)
    119         else:
    120             try:
--> 121                 name = name.encode('ascii')
    122                 coding = h5t.CSET_ASCII
    123             except UnicodeEncodeError:

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

The problem is that I don't know how to get the information of `dataset_name` and `event_number`. By `item.parent`, the second line in my case, I guess the corresponding values should be `/` and `1`, which doesn't work.

Please find the file in the link if you need:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1UyTlIs325wbWhwR3NTVmFpWTg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded your file and took a look at it. After reading the `.hws` file you get a dictionary with exactly one key `"wfm_group0"` (You can see keys in the file by using `item.keys()`). The value to this key is again dictionary-like with the keys `"axes"`, `"id"`, `"traces"` and `"vector"`.

Don't know where you want to go from there, but maybe you can play around with this information and see where it gets you.

Comment: Thanks, by recursively checking the keys, I finally found the data and converted it to numpy array. It really is a 'Hierarchical' storage.